# How can I have a button be disabled with jQuery but also run server code once it's been clicked?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a button that will execute a stored procedure.  After it's been clicked, I want it disabled so that the user can't click it multiple times.  However, once it's been clicked, I also want to run some C# on the server side through an `onclick` event.  As of right now, all my code does is disable the button, but then it won't run the server side stuff.  Can this be achieved?  Here's my jQuery:

```
 $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true).val("Generating...");
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to just run some code, or would you like it to affect the html in your page, such as loading some content into a div?

Comment: I'm going to run a stored procedure when the button is clicked.  I may modify the page slightly (perhaps show confirmation text or something), but there isn't going to be data displayed on this page (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: I only ask because I was changing a flag in my database and wanted to dynamically show the user it had happened. so I used an actionresult and javascript .load on a div. I've posted my answer here, it should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ajax call to the server just after you hide/disable the button.

You can do something like this:

```
$("#btnGenerate").click(function () {  
    $(this).attr("disabled", true).val("Generating...");  
    // an ajax call to the server to call the stored procedure
    $.ajax({
         url: "CallStoredProcedure.aspx",
         context: $("#value"),
         success: function(){
                $(this).val("done!");
           }});  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the button just remove the click event handler.

```
$(this).unbind();
```

This will probably be less annoying to the user anyway because then they can still see the button being clicked but don't realize nothing is actually happening.

Then just place whatever AJAX call you need to trigger the server side code right after the unbind() call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved.  You do need to send something to the server though. Where's that code?  You should probably do this:

```
$("#btnGenerate").click(function () {

    // UPDATE THE BUTTON  
    $(this).val("Generating...");

    // PERFORM C# SERVER SIDE CODE

    // ON SERVER SIDE CODE SUCCESS, DISABLE THE BUTTON
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how javascript handles this sort of thing but if the user clicks the button twice quickly before it's been disabled there may already be another event trigger sitting in the queue causing the server request to fire twice.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to change anything on the page, like the confirmation text you mentioned, then you can create a div where you want the confirmation to be

```
<div id="confirmmessage">

</div>
```

Then set your javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function dowork() {
        $("#confirmmessage").load('/home/myfunction');                        
    }       
</script>
```

then in the home controller:

```
public ActionResult myfunction()
        {
            //DO Some work here, then return the view below, with a pass or fail maybe? anything
            return PartialView("mymessage");
        }
```

Last thing to do, create a partial view called "mymessage"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
 <h3>Work done!</h3>
```

That will load into your confirmmessage div the work done.. or if you like not done..

you can pass a string to the actionresult, or maybe set some session variables before calling it if you want to hide them

Hope that helps.

Martyn

Comment: Also, just thought, you can add some javascript on load to the partial view to enable the button again if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `Hidden Button` in your form.

### Mark Up

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
    style="display:none;position:absolute;left:-1000px;width:0px" 
    runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClick="ClickIt"/>

protected void ClickIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

`Disable your button` as you are already doing.

### JavaScript

```
$("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true).val("Generating...");
    });
```

Now, perform the click of your hidden button on clicking the original button. Move your code in the Hidden button handler.

### JavaScript

```
$("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true).val("Generating...");
        document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID').click();
    });
```

Finally, you can enable your button again in the definition of your Hidden Button. Hope this will help you